# Calculating and displaying date difference

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I have two dates which im loading into variables using

```
a=`date +%s`
b=`date +%s`
```

i want to know the difference between times e.g difference 00:00:10 and so on , i do calculate it using

```
diff=$(( b-a ))
echo "$(( diff/3600 )):$((( diff/60)%60)):$((diff%60))"
```

but the output is 0:0:07 , how can i convert it on 2points = on 00:00:07?

Answer (score 0):

If the string  length is 1 then added the zero with value

```
hour=$(( diff/3600 ))
min=$((( diff/60)%60))
sec=$((diff%60))
 [[ ${#hour} == 1 ]] && hour="0$hour" || hour="$hour" 
 [[ ${#min} == 1 ]] && min="0$min" || min="$min"
 [[ ${#sec} == 1 ]] && sec="0$sec" || sec="$sec"
 echo "$hour:$min:$sec"
```

Output:

```
         00:00:16
```

Comment: if i get this correctly this is syntax for test command , but what does  ${#hour} (hasthag) and && and || operands mean in unix? seems like its not the same like in other languages = and , or

Comment: # will return the length of the variable.
&& ,|| is the short form of ternary Operator like if ...else

Comment: ${#varname} is a length of the variable and  &&, || used  for the on of the sort form of ternary operator in bash . If the condition is true , it will return 0 with value other wise  return the value